# Problema ao executar runnable JAR: Unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema: estamos na fase de desenvolvimento de um projeto, que envolve as seguintes tecnologias, SQL Server, Hibernate, maven, quartz e java.

Após termino de uma das fases de codificação tentamos gerar um *runnable jar*, porém na hora de executa-lo nos deparamos com uma série de erros que envolvem o *jdbc driver* que não conseguimos resolver.

Erro gerado após execução do JAR:

```
C:\Users\-----\workspace\CadastroProcessosMaven\CadastroProcessosMaven\target>java -jar extrator-acoesnovas-jar-with-dependencies.jar
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default    configuration: logging only errors to the console. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at dao.MCPCPProcessoDAO.buscarProcessosPorSistema(MCPCPProcessoDAO.java:116)
at MainPackage.Crawler.consultarProcessos(Crawler.java:31)
at MainPackage.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:26)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at dao.util.ConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ConnectionFactory.java:20)... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureServic e(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:770)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:797)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:183)

    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    ... 28 more
```

Arquivo `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>CadastroProcessos</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<build>
    <finalName>extrator-acoesnovas</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- DEFINE AS CONFIGURAÇÕES DO MAVEN ASSEMBLER -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>

                    <!-- DEFINE QUAL É A CLASSE MAIN DA APLICAÇÃO -->
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>MainPackage.CrawlerVivo</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

                <!-- ADICIONO AO NOME DO JAR FINAL UM COMPLEMENTO DIZENDO QUE ELE CONTÉM 
                    AS DEPENDÊNCIAS -->

                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>

                    <!-- DETERMINO QUE O JAR GERADO INCLUIRÁ AS DEPENDÊNCIAS E ELAS SERÃO 
                        EMPACOTADAS JUNTO COM O PROJETO EM UM ÚNICO JAR -->

                    <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-core-js</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.intarsys.opensource</groupId>
        <artifactId>isrt</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Log Build Maven:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model           
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for    com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/sqljdbc4.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 134, column 16
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support      building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CadastroProcessos 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ CadastroProcessos ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\-----\workspace\CadastroProcessosFinal\CadastroProcessosMaven\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ CadastroProcessos ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @    CadastroProcessos ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 82 source files to C:\Users\------\workspace\CadastroProcessosFinal\CadastroProcessosMaven\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ CadastroProcessos ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ CadastroProcessos ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ CadastroProcessos ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ CadastroProcessos ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\-----\workspace\CadastroProcessosFinal\CadastroProcessosMaven\target\CadastroProcessos-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @   CadastroProcessos ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\------\workspace\CadastroProcessosFinal\CadastroProcessosMaven\target\CadastroProcessos-1.0.jar to C:\Users\-----\.m2\repository\br\com\finchsolucoes\CadastroProcessos\1.0\CadastroProcessos-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\-----\workspace\CadastroProcessosFinal\CadastroProcessosMaven\pom.xml to C:\Users\------\.m2\repository\br\com\finchsolucoes\CadastroProcessos\1.0\CadastroProcessos-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 47.167 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-23T08:28:15-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/494M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: O erro é por que, provavelmente, o driver não está no classpath. Só com isso não dá para saber o porque. Inclua o log, em texto, não imagem, horrível de ler isso. Inclua seu `pom.xml`, ou a parte do build nele que gera o jar.

Comment: realizei as edições que você pediu, me desculpe, caso você possa ajudar, ai está!

Comment: Veja que é lançada uma `ClassNotFoundException` e você define a dependência do *driver* do SQL Server como opcional (`<optional>true</optional>`), então realmente a dependência não está no *classpath*. Já tentou remover este trecho do `pom.xml`?

Comment: Fiz o que você disse, continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: E verificar se o driver foi empacotado, tu verificou? Vou tentar simular aqui assim que possível

Comment: então não foi, problema eh que ele não acha o driver jdbc sqlServer, não sei se é pq microsoft não tem em repositório público, tentei baixar o jar na mão colocar em uma pasta do projeto, apontar a dependência para esta pasta, também não funcionou, ou seja o maven não consegue baixar, e se eu baixo e aponto pro jar tbm não funciona

Comment: Não tem em repositório público mesmo não, ou instala ou referencia mesmo

Comment: Bom pra quem estiver sofrendo ai com o jdbcDriver, conseguimos resolver, crie manualmente dentro da pasta m2 do maven uma pasta pra dependência do sql server, baixa manualmente, cole dentro da pasta, de build, gere o jar e execute, um puta gambiarra mais foi o único jeito que funcionou, pois por repositório publico o maven não consegue encontrar

Answer (score 1):

A raiz do seu problema é um [`ClassNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html), por não existir a class no *classpath* da aplicação.

Como discutido a ausência desta classe no *classpath* é devido ao fato de ela não estar sendo empacotada.

Não existe (até onde eu saiba) a dependência em um repositório público, então você pode fazer de duas formas:

- instalar a dependência no seu repositório local e depois referenciá-la no seu `pom.xml`. Para isto, execute isto do diretório em que está o seu arquivo jar do driver (ou informe caminho completo em `file`):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

E no `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

- usando [dependências de sistema](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies), comumente usadoa neste caso. Um exemplo seria:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <!-- normalmente path não empacotado e que deve estar -->
    <!-- presente no ambiente em que o projeto será executado -->
    <systemPath>${propriedade.path}/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Fiz de um jeito aqui que funcionou, esta no ultimo comentário da resposta acima, vou testar do seu jeito pois parece melhor, obrigado